# Problemas com envio de formulário

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5

Estou com um problema no meu código. 
Tenho uma página que possui um formulário modal que é aberto ao clicar em uma botão do menu do cabeçalho (que é o mesmo em todas as páginas do site e é adicionado nas páginas via PHP).

Eu envio o formulário e até ai tudo bem, ele vai para o meu email. Só que quando eu aperto F5 para atualizar a página, o formulário é novamente enviado. Estou enviando o formulário diretamente do html para o PHP. Porém já tentei utilizar JavaScript/jQuery para fazer esse envio e o erro persiste.

Vou colar o código aqui para vocês verem se podem me ajudar.

```html
<!-- HEADER DO CABEÇALHO -->
    
<?php

  require_once('destino-contato.php'); //CHAMANDO O ARQUIVO DESTINO.PHP QUE CONTÉM O ENVIO DO FORMULÁRIO E DO ARQUIVO ANEXADO NO FORMULÁRIO 

?>
           
    
    <header class="row" id="cabecalho">
    
     <div class="row hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="cabecalho-superior">
      
       <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" id="cabecalho-superior-acerto">
       
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-5" id="div-redes">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/jcacontadores/" target="blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/footer_redesFace.png"></a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/jcacontadores/" target="blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/footer_redesInsta.png"></a>
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jca-contadores-406/" target="blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/footer_redesLink.png"></a>
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLb6KnKGdjKh-usDWdZ93yg?view_as=subscriber" target="blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/footer_redesYouTube.png"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-7" id="div-menu">
         <ul class="" id="ul-cabecalho-superior-direita">
          <li><a href="https://encurtador.com.br/gOPZ6" target="_blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/icone-zap.png"> Whatsapp </a></li>
          <li><a href="mailto:contato@jcacontadores.com.br"><img src="_imagens/icones/icone-email.png"> contato@jcacontadores.com.br</a></li>
          <li><a class="estilo-botoes" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-contato"><button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" style="font-family: Franklin Gothic; font-size: 100%">Fale com um Especialista</button></a></li>
         </ul>  
        </div>
        
       </div> 
      
     </div>
        
    <!-- ÁREA DOS MENUS SUPERIORES -->
   
     <nav class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="nav-principal">
     
      <div class="visible-xs col-xs-12">
       <a href="index.php"><img src="_imagens/logo-216x93.png" style="width:20%"></a>
      </div>
            
     
     
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" id="acerto-margin-menu-movel">
      
       <div class="hidden-xs">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="_imagens/logo-216x93.png"></a>
       </div>
       
       <ul id="menu-desktop">
        <li><a href="area-cliente.php" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="margin-right: 0.5% font-family: Franklin Gothic; font-size: 90%" id="bot-area-cliente"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>&nbsp ÁREA DO CLIENTE</button></a></li>
       </ul>
       
       <ul id="menu-desktop">
        <li class="li-redes-clientes" id="li-redes-clientes-home"><a class="a-menu" href="index.php" style="font-weight: bold;">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="li-redes-clientes" id="li-redes-clientes-sobre"><a class="a-menu" href="quemsomos.php" style="font-weight: bold; cursor:pointer" id="botao-quemsomos">QUEM SOMOS</a></li>
                        
        <li class="li-redes-clientes" id="li-redes-clientes-servicos" role="presentation" class="dropdown li-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle a-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="font-weight: bold;">
            SERVIÇOS<span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="submenu-servicos">
            <li class="li-submenu-servicos"><a class="a-submenu-servicos" href="servicos-fiscal.php">INTELIGÊNCIA FISCAL E TRIBUTÁRIA</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu-servicos"><a class="a-submenu-servicos" href="servicos-departamento-pessoal.php">DEPARTAMENTO PESSOAL</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu-servicos"><a class="a-submenu-servicos" href="servicos-contabilidade.php">SERVIÇOS CONTÁBEIS</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu-servicos"><a class="a-submenu-servicos" href="servicos-auditoria.php">AUDITORIA</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu-servicos"><a class="a-submenu-servicos" href="servicos-consultoria.php">CONSULTORIA</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu-servicos"><a class="a-submenu-servicos" href="servicos-incentivos-fiscais.php">BENEFÍCIOS FISCAIS</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu-servicos"><a class="a-submenu-servicos" href="servicos-area-societaria-legalizacao.php">LEGALIZAÇÃO DE EMPRESAS</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu-servicos"><a class="a-submenu-servicos" href="servicos-analise-de-produtos.php">ANÁLISE CADASTRAL DE PRODUTOS</a></li>
          </ul>
                   
        </li>
                      
        
        <li class="li-redes-clientes" id="li-redes-clientes-carreiras" role="presentation" class="dropdown li-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle a-menu" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="font-weight: bold;">
          CARREIRAS<span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="submenu-carreiras">
            <li class="li-submenu-carreiras"><a class="a-submenu-carreiras" href="contato-despertando.php">PROGRAMA DESPERTANDO TALENTOS</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu-carreiras"><a class="a-submenu-carreiras" href="contato-profissionais.php">PROGRAMA PROFISSIONAIS EXPERIENTES</a></li>
            
          </ul>
                         
        </li>
        
        <li class="li-redes-clientes" id="li-redes-clientes-blog"><a class="a-menu" href="https://jcasistemas.info/" target="blank" style="font-weight: bold;">BLOG</a></li>
        <li class="li-redes-clientes" id="li-redes-clientes-contato"><a class="a-menu" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-contato" style="font-weight: bold;">CONTATO</a></li>
       </ul>  
       
                      
              
      </div> 
           
     </nav> 
     
     
     
     
     
     
     
     <!------------ MENU MÓVEL -------------->
     
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top hidden-md hidden-lg" id="nav-movel">
     
     
     <!--------- DIV DAS REDES SOCIAIS ----------->
     
      <div class="row visible-xs visible-sm" id="cabecalho-superior-movel">
      
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="cabecalho-superior-acerto">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/jcacontadores/" target="blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/footer_redesFace.png"></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/jcacontadores/" target="blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/footer_redesInsta.png"></a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jca-contadores-406/" target="blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/footer_redesLink.png"></a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLb6KnKGdjKh-usDWdZ93yg?view_as=subscriber" target="blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/footer_redesYouTube.png"></a>
        <a href="https://encurtador.com.br/gOPZ6" target="_blank"><img src="_imagens/icones/icone-zap.png"></a>
        <a href="mailto:contato@jcacontadores.com.br"><img src="_imagens/icones/icone-email.png"></a>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-contato"><button class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Fale com Especialista</button></a>
       </div>
       
      </div>
      
     
       <div class="navbar-header">
       
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#movelmenu" arial-expanded="false">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        
        
         <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">
          <img src="_imagens/logo-216x93.png" class="logo-menu-movel">
         </a>
        
       </div>
       
           
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="movelmenu">
       
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="ul-movel">
         <li class="li-menu"><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
         <li role="presentation" class="dropdown li-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            SOBRE<span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="li-submenu" style="border-bottom: none; margin-bottom:-5px"><a href="quemsomos.php">QUEM SOMOS</a></li>
          </ul>
                   
         </li>
         
         <li role="presentation" class="dropdown li-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            SERVIÇOS<span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="li-submenu"><a href="servicos-fiscal.php">INTELIGÊNCIA FISCAL E TRIBUTÁRIA</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu"><a href="servicos-departamento-pessoal.php">DEPARTAMENTO PESSOAL</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu"><a href="servicos-contabilidade.php">SERVIÇOS CONTÁBEIS</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu"><a href="servicos-auditoria.php">AUDITORIA</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu"><a href="servicos-consultoria.php">CONSULTORIA</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu"><a href="servicos-incentivos-fiscais.php">BENEFÍCIOS FISCAIS</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu"><a href="servicos-area-societaria-legalizacao.php">LEGALIZAÇÃO DE EMPRESAS</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu" style="border-bottom: none; margin-bottom:-5px"><a href="servicos-analise-de-produtos.php">ANÁLISE CADASTRAL DE PRODUTOS</a></li>
          </ul>
                   
         </li>
         
         <li role="presentation" class="dropdown li-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            CARREIRAS<span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="li-submenu"><a href="contato-despertando.php">PROGRAMA DESPERTANDO TALENTOS</a></li>
            <li class="li-submenu" style="border-bottom: none; margin-bottom:-5px"><a href="contato-profissionais.php">PROGRAMA PROFISSIONAIS EXPERIENTES</a></li>
          </ul>
                  
         </li>
         <li class="li-menu"><a href="https://jcasistemas.info/" target="_blank">BLOG</a></li>
         <li class="li-menu"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-contato">CONTATO</a></li>
         <li class="li-menu"><a href="area-cliente.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> &nbsp ÁREA DO CLIENTE</a></li>
                 
        </ul>
        
        
       </div>
     
     </nav>

      
    </header>
    
        
    
    
    
    <!-- MODAL CONTATO DO MENU SUPERIOR -->
    
      <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="modal-contato">
       <div class="modal-dialog" id="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header" id="modal-header">
          <button class="close"
            aria-label="close"
            data-dismiss="modal">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Fale Conosco</h4>
         </div>
         
         <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
           <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   
           <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
            <label for="nome-modal-contato">Nome *</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nome-modal-contato" id="nome-modal-contato"  maxlength="80" required>
           </div>
           
           <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
            <label for="email-modal-contato">Email *</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email-modal-contato" id="email-modal-contato" placeholder="Email" maxlength="60" required>
           </div>
          
           <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
            <label for="empresa-modal-contato">Empresa</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="empresa-modal-contato" id="empresa-modal-contato" placeholder="Informe o nome da sua empresa" maxlength="60">  
           </div>
           
           <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
            <label for="fone-modal-contato">Telefone </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fone-modal-contato" id="fone-modal-contato" pattern="\([0-9]{3}\) [0-9]{4,5}-[0-9]{4}$" placeholder="(999) 9999-9999 ou 99999-9999">  
           </div>
           
           <div class="form-group col-lg-8">
            <label for="empresa-modal-contato">Assunto *</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="assunto-modal-contato" id="assunto-modal-contato" required>
              <option value="Desejo abrir uma empresa">Desejo abrir uma empresa</option>
              <option value="Quero conhecer os serviços">Quero conhecer os serviços</option>
              <option value="Quero saber mais informações sobre a empresa">Quero saber mais informações sobre a empresa</option>
              <option value="Quero saber mais informações sobre a serviços">Quero saber mais informações sobre a serviços</option>
              <option value="Programa Despertando Talentos">Programa Despertando Talentos</option>
              <option value="Programa Profissionais Experientes">Programa Profissionais Experientes</option>
              <option value="Outros assuntos">Outros assuntos</option>
            </select>  
           </div>
                     
           
           <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
            <label for="comentario-modal-contato">Comentários (Opcional)</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="comentario-modal-contato" id="comentario-modal-contato" style="resize: none" rows="4" maxlength="400"></textarea>
           </div>
                   
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="enviar-modal-contato" id="enviar-modal-contato" value="Enviar">
          </form>
                          
           
         </div>
         
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      
      
      
      
<!-- AQUI ABAIXO É O CÓDIGO QUE ESTÁ NO ARQUIVO DESTINO-CONTATO.PHP, QUE É O ARQUIVO QUE FAZ O ENVIO DO FORMULÁRIO -->


<?php
 
 setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');
 setlocale(LC_TIME, 'portuguese-brazilian'); 
 
 //CRIANDO MENSAGEM DE ERRO -- NO CASO DE ERRO 

 $array_erro = array
 (
  UPLOAD_ERR_OK => "Sem erro.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE => "O arquivo enviado excede o limite definido na diretiva upload_max_filesize do php.ini.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE => "O arquivo excede o limite definido em MAX_FILE_SIZE no formulário HTML",
  UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL => "O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE => "Nenhum arquivo foi enviado.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR => "Pasta temporária ausente.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE => "Falha em escrever o arquivo em disco.",
  UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION => "Uma extensão do PHP interrompeu o upload do arquivo."
 ); 
 
 
 if( isset($_POST["enviar-modal-contato"]) )
 { 
 
  

  
   //ENVIANDO O FORMULÁRIO PARA O SERVIDOR DE EMAIL
   
     
    $nome_modal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome-modal-contato', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $email_modal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email-modal-contato', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $empresa_modal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'empresa-modal-contato', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $telefone_modal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fone-modal-contato', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $assunto_modal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'assunto-modal-contato', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $comentario_modal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'comentario-modal-contato', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    
   
    
   
    
    
    
    //Criar Variáveis de envio
    $destino = "thipetherson@gmail.com";
    $remetente = "thiago@thiagopetherson.tech"; //Aqui tem que ser um email do próprio domínio. Email do site de hospedagem (Falta preencher)
    $assunto_format = "Formulário de Contato - SITE JCA CONTADORES"; //Pode ser qualquer mensagem
    $assunto = utf8_decode($assunto_format);
    
    //Montar o corpo da mensagem (Essa mensagem é a que chegará na caixa de email)
    
    
    $mensagem = utf8_decode("SOLICITAÇÃO DE CONTATO VINDO DO SITE\n");
    $mensagem .= utf8_decode("Usuário: ") . utf8_decode($nome_modal) . "\n";
    $mensagem .= "Email: " . utf8_decode($email_modal) . "\n";
    $mensagem .= "Empresa: " . utf8_decode($empresa_modal) . "\n";
    $mensagem .= "Telefone: " . utf8_decode($telefone_modal) . "\n";
    $mensagem .= "Assunto: " . utf8_decode($assunto_modal) . "\n \n";
    $mensagem .= utf8_decode("Mensagem do Usuário:"). "\n\n" . utf8_decode($comentario_modal);
    
    
    return mail($destino, $assunto, $mensagem, $remetente);
    
     
 }
 


?>
```

Se quiserem ver o problema no próprio site, é só acessar thiagopetherson.tech

OBS: Não posso utilizar o header("location") no arquivo destino-php, pois o mesmo cabeçalho (e o botão modal que abre o formulário) está em várias páginas. Com isso não posso redirecionar para uma página fixa.

Abaixo está a imagem da mensagem que aparece no navegador quando dou F5.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, com a ajuda de um amigo. Utilizei o $.POST do jquery, para enviar os dados para o arquivo PHP que faz o envio do formulário.

Vou deixar o código aqui HTML (Do form), JavaScript (jQuery do $.POST) e PHP (De envio do email).

```js
$('#formulario-contato-cliente').submit(function()
 {
  $.post("destino-contato.php", {"nome-modal-contato": $("input[name=nome-modal-contato]").val(), "email-modal-contato": $("input[name=email-modal-contato]").val(), "empresa-modal-contato": $("input[name=empresa-modal-contato]").val(), "fone-modal-contato": $("input[name=fone-modal-contato]").val(), "assunto-modal-contato": $("select[name=assunto-modal-contato]").val(), "comentario-modal-contato": $("textarea[name=comentario-modal-contato]").val() }, 
  function(data)
  {
   $("#h4-form").html( data );
   $("#h4-form").css('color','DarkGreen');
   
  });
  
  return false;
 });
```

```html
 <form id="formulario-contato-cliente">
   
           <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
            <label for="nome-modal-contato">Nome *</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nome-modal-contato" id="nome-modal-contato"  maxlength="80" required>
           </div>
           
           <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
            <label for="email-modal-contato">Email *</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email-modal-contato" id="email-modal-contato" placeholder="Email" maxlength="60" required>
           </div>
          
           <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
            <label for="empresa-modal-contato">Empresa</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="empresa-modal-contato" id="empresa-modal-contato" placeholder="Informe o nome da sua empresa" maxlength="60">  
           </div>
           
           <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
            <label for="fone-modal-contato">Telefone </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fone-modal-contato" id="fone-modal-contato" pattern="[0-9]{11,12}$" placeholder="DDD+Telefone ">  
           </div>
           
           <div class="form-group col-lg-8">
            <label for="empresa-modal-contato">Assunto *</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="assunto-modal-contato" id="assunto-modal-contato" required>
              <option value="Desejo abrir uma empresa">Desejo abrir uma empresa</option>
              <option value="Quero conhecer os serviços">Quero conhecer os serviços</option>
              <option value="Quero saber mais informações sobre a empresa">Quero saber mais informações sobre a empresa</option>
              <option value="Quero saber mais informações sobre a serviços">Quero saber mais informações sobre os serviços</option>
              <option value="Programa Despertando Talentos">Programa Despertando Talentos</option>
              <option value="Programa Profissionais Experientes">Programa Profissionais Experientes</option>
              <option value="Outros assuntos">Outros assuntos</option>
            </select>  
           </div>
                     
           
           <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
            <label for="comentario-modal-contato">Comentários (Opcional)</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="comentario-modal-contato" id="comentario-modal-contato" style="resize: none" rows="4" maxlength="400"></textarea>
           </div>
                   
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="enviar-modal-contato" id="enviar-modal-contato">Enviar</button>
          </form>
                    
                    


<!-- Arquivo destino-contato.php Que faz o envio dos dados do form

<?php
 
 setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');
 setlocale(LC_TIME, 'portuguese-brazilian'); 
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  //CRIANDO MENSAGEM DE ERRO -- NO CASO DE ERRO 
 
  

if(isset($_POST))
{
 
 $nome_modal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome-modal-contato', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
 $email_modal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email-modal-contato', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
 $empresa_modal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'empresa-modal-contato', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
 $telefone_modal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fone-modal-contato', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
 $assunto_modal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'assunto-modal-contato', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
 $comentario_modal = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'comentario-modal-contato', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
 
 
 
 
 
 $headers = 'From: thiago@thiagopetherson.tech' . "\r\n"; // Coloque o da sua hospedagem
 $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['email-modal-contato'] . "\r\n"; // A quem vai ser enviado uma resposta (vai ser o email de quem entrou em contato)
 $headers .= 'Bcc: thiagopetherson@bol.com.br' . "\r\n"; // Alguém diferente do destinatário que vai receber o e-mail.
 $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 
 $destino = 'thipetherson@gmail.com';
 $assunto_format = "Formulário de Contato - SITE JCA CONTADORES"; //Pode ser qualquer mensagem
 $assunto = utf8_decode($assunto_format);
 
 $mensagem = utf8_decode("SOLICITAÇÃO DE CONTATO VINDO DO SITE\n\n");
 $mensagem .= utf8_decode("Usuário: ") . utf8_decode($nome_modal) . "\n";
 $mensagem .= "Email: " . utf8_decode($email_modal) . "\n";
 $mensagem .= "Empresa: " . utf8_decode($empresa_modal) . "\n";
 $mensagem .= "Telefone: " . utf8_decode($telefone_modal) . "\n";
 $mensagem .= "Assunto: " . utf8_decode($assunto_modal) . "\n \n";
 $mensagem .= utf8_decode("Mensagem do Usuário:"). "\n" . utf8_decode($comentario_modal);
 
 if( mail($destino, $assunto , $mensagem, $headers)  )
 {   
  die("Mensagem enviada com sucesso.\n Em breve entraremos em contato");
 }
 else
 {
  die("Houve um erro a enviar o e-mail");
 }
}
else
{
 die("Os dados não foram enviados");
}

 
 
  

?>
```

Desde já, agradeço a todos os envolvidos que tentaram ajudar. Obrigado !

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se ao atualizar a página a requisição _POST está sendo enviada novamente. Insira esse código no seu arquivo do formulário:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST))
{
    echo "<script>window.alert('POST existe');</script>";
}
?>
```

É melhor você redirecionar o formulário para outro arquivo que contém a validação e o disparo do _POST para o seu e-mail, e depois enviado com sucesso você redireciona o usuário para outra página ou retorna para a anterior.

Comment: Acho que essa sua opção não é é muito válida para minha situação. O meu arquivo de disparo do email já fica em um arquivo separado. Porém, eu não posso redirecionar (utilizando o header) para a mesma página, pq esse formulário fica em uma cabeçalho que está em toda as janelas do meu site. Então não tem como eu redirecionar para uma página fixa. Pois o usuário pode abrir esse mesmo formulário estando em qualquer página do site.

Comment: Você testou se o _POST está sendo enviado ao atualizar? Primeiro é necessário alguns testes para adequar a solução.

Comment: Como assim, Eliseu ? Tenho quase certeza que o POST está sendo enviado. Pois o email está chegando duplicado na minha caixa de email. E outra coisa, eu fiz exibir uma mensagem de confirmação que só aparece quando o email é enviado, e quando eu aperto F5 e atualizado a página, essa mensagem aparece. Já rodei tudo e não achei uma resposta pra isso.

Comment: adiciona no final do disparo  de e-mail uma URL redirecionada, para a pagina anterior: header('Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "');

Comment: Desse modo vai levar o usuário para a mesma página que ele está, ou se não quer perder algum tipo de dado você pode usar em javascript <script>parent.location.href='<?php echo echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>';</script> que pode usar apenas para atualizar a página em modo redirect e podendo também enviar parâmetros <script>parent.location.href='<?php echo echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>'?var=X&var2=Y&var3=Z;</script>