# Unset não funciona

Tags: php

Não quero salvar um registro duas vezes ao dar *F5* na página.

Coloquei um `input type hidden` no formulário e estou verificando se ele foi iniciado para realizar um *insert*, e se foi dado o *insert* estou dando `unset` na variável `$_POST` que identifica o formulário.

```
<form action="#" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="formulario" value="1">

    <input type="text" name="nome" />

</form>

<?php

    $formulario = $_POST['formulario'];

    if ((isset($formulario)) && ($formulario == '1')) {

        $name = $_POST['nome'];

        if (mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO user (`nome`) VALUES ('$name')")) {

            unset($formulario);

        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: Tereza, em vez de dar unset, você pode atribuir outro valor para ela, por exemplo, '2'.

Comment: @RodrigoTognin Isso não fará diferença. Ao atualizar a página, uma nova requisição será feita com os mesmos dados e será feito a inserção igual.

Comment: você também pode dar um `header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` ele vai redirecionar pra mesma página e não vai ter o `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

Tereza, talvez você tenha que criar o arquivo com o código php em outra página. 
Ou então, utilizar JavaScript com AJAX. (Já tive um problema parecido com este)

Vou colocar a resposta só com a utilização do PHP. E depois vou deixar o link para a resposta de uma pergunta que eu fiz (sobre um problema parecido com este só que utilizando JavaScript/jQuery.

**Resposta com PHP:**

Aqui você teria que criar um outro arquivo (Digamos que será o arquivo enviar.php).

```html
<form action="enviar.php" method="POST">

  <input type="text" name="nome" />

</form>



<!-- Arquivo enviar.php -->


<?php
 

    if($_POST) 
    {

    $name = $_POST['nome'];


      $inserindo = "INSERT INTO nome_da_tabela(nome_do_campo) VALUES('$name');";
 
 $resultado_insert = mysqli_query($conn,  $inserindo);
         

     }
      
     header(location:"pagina-do-seu-form.html");
    

?>

  <!-- O HEADER vai redirecionar para página que contém seu form -->
```

Aqui tem o link da pergunta (feita por mim) com a resposta, porém utilizando o JavaScript.

[Link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/363032/problemas-com-envio-de-formul%C3%A1rio)